# Books on Vertical-Landing Vertical-Takeoff (VTVL) of Rockets? or Rocket Design in General?

Tags: spacex, rockets, falcon-9, blue-origin, vtvl

I am working on a rocket control system design and I am trying to understand the the fundamental principles and concepts to design an efficient controller for recovering and landing the rocket, something like what SpaceX, Blue Origin, and Linkspace are doing.

I was wondering if there any books/material that I could follow for the control system design and simulation as well (MATLAB Preferred).

I have added this link for the latest Linkspace video on their amazing success for the vertical landing.

Thanks!

Comment: Rubin S.  Longitudinal Instability of Liquid Rockets Due to Propulsion Feedback (POGO) / S. Rubin // J. Spacescraft and Rockets. – 1966. – Vol .3. – No. 8. – P. 1188 – 1195
Preventing POGO on Titan IVB. Crosslink. // The Aerospace Corporation magazine of advances in aerospace technology. – Summer 2003. – P. 3
Tsujimoto Y.  Unified Treatment of Flow Instabilities of Turbomachinaries /
Y. Tsujimoto, K. Kamijo, C. Brenen  // AIAA. – 1999. – Paper 99-2678.

Comment: @A.Rumlin maybe write that up as an answer then? Comments are considered temporary, if you post as an answer it helps increase the visibility to readers and shows that the question has an answer posted. Right now the question shows as "unanswered" so people may skip it and not see your comment.

Comment: I don't think there is anything specific here, but you may find some generally helpful references: [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Flying rocket - this is a very difficult mathematical problem. It is impossible to describe in two words.

Comment: @A.Rumlin the question only asks for sources to read, which you have provided. "I was wondering if there any books/material that I could follow..."

Comment: @uhoh I am afraid that other books will be in Russian.
https://mash-xxl.info/pic1/197239255068001016237077097137114028146177135212.png